# django on AWS with multiple settings file

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, django-settings

Well, I had one setting file before and it was working perfectly both in local and AWS of course with both the database configuration in one setting file. When ever I use to push my code on AWS I would comment my local db configuration and then push. So for sure, that's annoying. I can't comment and uncomment constantly both the database configuration in one file.

Therefore, I decided to have 2 setting files. one for the local and the other for AWS.

Once I pulled the code into AWS server and run migrations

```
python manage.py migrate --settings=settings.staging
```

It worked and migrated. By the way, this is the setting file which resides my RDS configuration. Now the moment I hit the endpoints via postmant the output is as

```
OperationalError at /account/v1/login
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

means it is still reading the default settings file. How come I make the server run this particular staging setting file. Do I have to declare it on nginx, supervisor or gunicorn?
I'm using these 3 services as well.

Below is my settings file for staging.

```
from .base import *

# --------------- AWS RDS ---------------
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        # 'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db name here',
        'HOST': 'RDS host here',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass here',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

This is my complete staging.py file. which only have this while the rest of the setting is being imported from base.py which is a default setting file. Also it has the local settings.

Any recommendations?

This is also what I've tried.

```
import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname()
if hostname == "staging":
     from settings.staging import *
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this issue is using hostnames. We have 1 settings file with all the default settings. We then import specific files depending on the hostname. Of course you could also use things like IAM-instance roles or something.

We would have this in the default settings file:

```
import socket
DATABASE = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', ...}}
hostname = socket.gethostname()
if hostname == "staging-blabla"
    from staging import *
```

`staging.py` would contain the following:

```
DATABASE = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', ...}}
```

Comment: hi there, thank you for your answer. but I am still facing the same issue on server which says 'Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?' . Any Idea?

Comment: Are you using PostGres local too? Or SQLite?

Comment: Postgres local yes. and RDS

Comment: as said it was working perfectly before I had separate file for staging

Comment: Can you show the import logic you use to include the staging settings file?

Comment: I did exactly to you said and it was perfectly working. but I have no idea why my default setting file being called which prompts this error. I have updated my question.